# List all files that haven't been edited in a year in CVS

Tags: version-control, cvs

How do I get a list of all the files have haven't been changed in the past year in a repository in CVS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can easily do this using ViewVC (or ViewCVS as it was called formerly). What it does is build a SQL database of all files and their commits (with comments and authors) that you can easily query in many ways.

You can download it from http://www.viewvc.org/. You will have to set up a MySQL server to store the data and have access to the physical repository directory on the CVS server to import your existing repository commits via the `cvsdbadmin` tool:

```
cvsdbadmin rebuild /var/lib/cvs
```

where `/var/lib/cvs` is your repository location. The database connection info is stored in the ViewVC config file.

Depending on the repository size this might run anywhere from a few seconds to several hours. Once it is finished, you can use regular SQL query tools to find out all sorts of information about your commits - we use it to very quickly generate change logs.
Using a [CVS loginfo script](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.11.21/cvs_18.html) (also included with ViewVC) we update the database on-the-fly whenever someone commits a file to CVS.

It can also be very helpful if you committed something by accident (see [this blog post](http://dschneller.blogspot.com/2007/09/value-of-cvs-commit-database.html)); as CVS commits are not transactional this can be a tough one to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think to do this is to get a list of every file changed in the last year (here I use 2008-05-08 as the one year ago date):

```
cvs history -c -D2008-05-08
```

and compare against a listing of every file currently in the repository.   Those not in the listing generated by `cvs history` have not been modified in the last year.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the repository, you can do a search to look for files that have a last-modified date of over a year ago.  In CVS, each file has a corresponding repository file.  (This wouldn't work in Subversion, since the repository is in an opaque format.)

Answer (score 0):

CVS diff option to show identical files (--report-identical-files) seems broken, at least for me. You can just checkout old version:

```
cvs co -D "1 year old" proj
```

And use good old diff to find identical files:

```
diff --recursive --report-identical-files --brief | grep identical
```